# How to turn 'this' SELECT to multiple strings

Tags: php, mysql, string

How I can turn this SELECT to output with strings (which is below this example)?

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a87fa/4)

```
nose_1

|id|class|about_education|
| 1|    1|            a01|
| 2|    0|            a02|

coins_2

|id|class|about_education|
| 1|    1|            a01|
| 2|    0|            a02|

money_3

|id|class|about_education|
| 1|    1|            a01|
| 2|    1|            a10|


SELECT 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN about_education = 'a01' and class = 1 then 1 else 0 end) a01,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN about_education = 'a02' and class = 1 then 1 else 0 end) a02, 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN about_education = 'a03' and class = 1 then 1 else 0 end) a03, 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN about_education = 'a04' and class = 1 then 1 else 0 end) a04, 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN about_education = 'a05' and class = 1 then 1 else 0 end) a05, 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN about_education = 'a06' and class = 1 then 1 else 0 end) a06, 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN about_education = 'a07' and class = 1 then 1 else 0 end) a07, 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN about_education = 'a08' and class = 1 then 1 else 0 end) a08, 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN about_education = 'a09' and class = 1 then 1 else 0 end) a09,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN about_education = 'a10' and class = 1 then 1 else 0 end) a10
FROM 
(
  SELECT id,class,about_education from nose_1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id,class,about_education FROM coins_2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id,class,about_education FROM money_3
) t
```

**Output:**

```
$check_a01 = 3;
$check_a02 = 0;
$check_a03 = 0;
$check_a04 = 0;
$check_a05 = 0;
$check_a06 = 0;
$check_a07 = 0;
$check_a08 = 0;
$check_a09 = 0;
$check_a10 = 1;
```

*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.*

Answer (score 1):

You can put all the 1's after THEN in quotes and all the 0's after ELSE in quotes.

```
then '1' else '0' end
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn`t understand your requirement, I hope below code may helpful for you

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT('$check_',
            about_education,
            ' = ',
            SUM(CASE
                WHEN
                    SUBSTRING(t.about_education,
                        2,
                        LENGTH(t.about_education)) = a.id
                        AND class = 1
                THEN
                    1
                ELSE 0
            END),
            ';') AS output
FROM
    (SELECT 
        class, about_education
    FROM
        nose_1 UNION ALL SELECT 
        class, about_education
    FROM
        coins_2 UNION ALL SELECT 
        class, about_education
    FROM
        money_3) t
        JOIN
    (SELECT 1 AS Id UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10) a ON SUBSTRING(t.about_education,
        2,
        LENGTH(t.about_education)) = a.id
GROUP BY t.about_education;
```